# How to use PHP to access query string variables created by History.PushState without ajax and without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Thanks to HTML5's extension to the Javascript's History API, Javascript developers now enjoy greater control over the browser's history and can even change the state of a given page and provide a bookmarkable address to their users without having to reload the page.

On the PHP (or server-) side, however, things are a little bit different. Take the following URL as an example:

`http://somesite.com/?user=8796&fname=john&lname=doe`.

When the user first navigates to this page, using PHP, a PHP developer could access the information passed in the URL on the server-side using the `GET` super-global, e.g:

```
$user_id = $_GET['user'];
$user_firstname = $_GET['fname'];
$user_lastname  = $_GET['lname'];
```

Now, upon the click of a button, or any other user-initiated event, Javascript code kicks in, using the History.PushState method and changes the query string parameters, so that we now have the URL like so

`http://somesite.com/?user=7647&fname=jane&lname=doe`.

For a Javascript developer, they can retrieve the query string parameters by parsing the URL and updating the page's content accordingly via AJAX. Not so, however, for PHP. The page has to be reloaded for the PHP script to have access to the just-updated query string parameters.

Is there a way it is possible, even if remotely or theoretically, for PHP to gain access to a URL/query string created with Javascript's History.PushState method without having to reload the page, and without the intermediary of AJAX?

Comment: There'd have to be *some* communication from the client to the server. If not ajax, then what? Web sockets maybe?  The PHP environment is only related to the client environment by the network.

Comment: Well, if you successfully avoided every possible way of two systems to talk to each other via common interfaces, all you're left with is quantum entanglement. It's theoretically possible, it doesn't require page reload and it's not AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

The `History.pushState()` JavaScript API runs in the browser. PHP runs on the server. So there is no way for PHP to know about the new URL and query string without JavaScript letting it know over the network somehow. The obvious ways this might happen are for the user to reload the page or for the web page to send an XHR/AJAX request to the server.

@Pointy mentions [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets), and there may be other ways to send information to the server, but without knowing why you want to avoid AJAX (which seems perfectly suited to this task), it's impossible to say if something else would meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `History.PushState` you are manipulating the browser history. Nothing is sent to the server.

> Using history.pushState() changes the referrer that gets used in the HTTP header for XMLHttpRequest objects created after you change the state. 
>   [[Mozilla Developer Network]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

The server will not know that you appended anything. It is like changing the background-color with JavaScript. You have to make a request to the server to let it know about what you did in the browser.

It seems right to make an AJAX request at the same time that you `History.PushState` the browser.

If you are doing navigation by `History.PushState` and AJAX calls, I would encourage you to read [AJAX Navigation Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/Example) at Mozilla Developer Network which is written with JavaScript and PHP.

Make sure to remember about the limited support for `History.PushState`.